# How to tell which alignment to use, given a datatype

Tags: .net, winforms

I made my own datagrid. The columns each have data of a certain type.

I'd like a easy way already built into the framework to tell, given a `Type` shown in the grid column, to determine the alignment.

I could have a case statement: string left, boolean middle, else right.

```vb
  Private Function GetAlignment() As ContentAlignment
    Select Case Me.Type.Name
      Case "String"
        Return ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
      Case Else
        Return ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    End Select
  End Function
```

but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: It might help if you would post the case statement you have in mind.

Comment: @Blam, ok it's there now

Comment: You may want to let the user set the defaults they choose. Also, you may want to consider other languages that work from right to left as in Arabic. You could detect this using System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft.

Comment: @EmmadKareem, thanks, right now the the users of this application are all use US-en. But I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @EmmadKareem, yes ultimately I want them to be able to override. These are the defaults.

Comment: Case looks OK.  Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @Blam, winforms. I was looking for some magic like (I am making this up) `System.Drawing.Alignment.FromType(Type)` lol

Comment: Add that tag as it could change the answer.  Like in WPF I would say use a property.

Comment: @Blam, ok I added that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a big case statement, you can tell if a type is numeric with this function:

```vb
  'Return true if a type is a numeric type.
  Public Function IsTypeNumeric(ByVal Type As Type) As Boolean
    ' All the numeric types have bits 11xx set whereas non numeric do not.
    ' That is if you include char type which is 4(decimal) = 100(binary).
    Return Not Type.IsArray AndAlso (System.Type.GetTypeCode(Type) And &HC)
  End Function
```

At that point you can do a little wrapper function on that to include Date if desired.